# http post and get service

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a service as follows

```
  angular.module('starter.service')
   .factory('authService', function($http) {
     var service = {};

     service.GetByUsername = function() {
       return $http.get('/js/user.json');
     }

    return service;
  })
```

i just need to know two things, 
1. why its is declaring a object named service ?
2.its a service for getting an object, what changes should i change to add another function to post a object(do it in the same code)? dont remove current functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using the factory method to create a service, so you need to create an object and return it (*Dependency Injection will make sure this object is only instantiated once so it is used as a singleton*). 
   **Whether this object you are creating is called "service" or any other way, it doesn't matter**, it will work anyway.
2. As Shankar shown in his example, adding more methods to your service is as easy as adding more methods to the object you are declaring. To clarify the example, I'll add the argument you want to post, and let whoever is using the service to decide what to do with the returned promise (as you do in GET method):

   ```
   angular.module('starter.service')
   .factory('authService', function($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.GetByUsername = function() {
      return $http.get('/js/user.json');
    }

    service.PostUser = function(user) {
      return $http.post("/url/to/post/user", user);
    }

    return service;
   })
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You question is not clear, but you can simply add new function to you factory service,

```js
 angular.module('starter.service')
   .factory('authService', function($http) {
     var service = {};

     service.GetByUsername = function() {
       return $http.get('/js/user.json');
     }
     
     service.PostUser = function() {

       var data = {}
       $http.post("/js/user.json", data).success(function(data, status) {

       })

     }
     return service;
   })
```